# Printing individual script arguments repeatedly prints all of them

Tags: python, windows

I'm reading "Learn Python the Hard Way" and I'm on exercise 13, but I'm running into a little trouble. Whenever I open up the command line and run the script and enter my argument variables, it's always duplicated on every line like this:

```
C:\users\blah\> program.py first second third
The script is called:['program.py','first','second','third']
Your first variable is:['program.py','first','second','third']
Your second variable is:['program.py','first','second','third']
Your third variable is:['program.py','first','second','third']
```

So instead of seeing this on every line I'm aiming for something that doesn't duplicate every line like this (without brackets):

```
C:\users\blah\> program.py first second third
The script is called:'program.py'
Your first variable is:'first'
Your second variable is:'second'
Your third variable is:'third'
```

This is my original code. Note I'm on Python 3.5, even though it's specified to use 2.7.

```
from sys import argv

script = argv
first = argv
second = argv
third = argv

print("The script is called:", script)
print("Your first variable is:", first)
print("Your second variable is:", second)
print("Your third variable is:", third)
```

Pretty sure the whole variable part is off.

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: it's basically the same as the example but anyway I run it it gives me exactly like the one above

Comment: So in order to answer your question someone has to go digging through the book. Post what you actually ran.

Comment: without code, there isn't much we can do, and we aren't going to track down that book to look at it.

Comment: @AgangDut - edit your original question and post your code there. Also try looking at my asnwer. It should be right'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the example is:

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv
```

When you execute your script with `program.py first second third` argv becomes a list containing the name of your script followed by each of the scripts arguments. So argv becomes this:

`argv = ['program.py', 'first', 'second', 'third']`

The line in the original code 'unpacks' the members of that list and assigns them to individual variables.  It is equivalent to:

```
script = argv[0]
first = argv[1]
second = argv[2]
third = argv[3]
```

It is simply a more concise way of expressing the above. This unpacking syntax is one of the things Zed Shaw is trying to teach with that example. When you changed the program to:

```
script = argv
first = argv
second = argv
third = argv
```

the 'unpacking' went away - each of your variables simply refers to the whole list, as you can see from the output of your modified program.

Comment: @AgangDut hopefully also shows why it's important to show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted the code but this is a very simple issue. When you provide command line arguments python takes it as a `list`. So when I say

```
import sys

print sys.argv
```

Then from the command line i type:

```
python program.py first second third
```

the output is what you are getting i.e. all the variables as a list.In order to get the words seperately use `list indices`. So to get the first argument you use `sys.argv[0]` which would give `program.py`

So your code would be like this:

```
import sys

print 'script name:', sys.argv[0]
print '1st var:', sys.argv[1]
#and so on
```

Comment: You have an extra quote at the end of `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: This answer is plain wrong. The program in question unpacks the argv. User either typed it wrong or made some mistake somewhere else. It works as is in python 2 and with parens added on the print in python 3. http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex13.html

Comment: @pvg - unpacking or list indices - either work. there was no requirement to only use unpacking. This is not code golf

Comment: @letsc the  question was about an existing program which was not posted. it upacks. the mistake the user made was modifying it in a way that does no unpacking. your answer has absolutely nothing to do with either of these, it's not a matter of code golf, it's a matter of answering a question before you have any idea what it is.

Comment: @pvg - _the question was about an existing program which was not posted_ . how would I know if it isnt posted? read the question title, then see what my answer does. If you dont think its related, think its time for you to learn python the hard way

Comment: exactly, how would you know? you can't, that's why you can't answer the question, which you did, stupidly. It is clear from the question it can't be answered without the user's code. The chapter itself, incidentally,  is called _Exercise 13: Parameters, *Unpacking*, Variables_ That's right. unpacking.

Comment: incidentally, you can easily edit the answer now to fix the the problem - you just have to explain how `foo = x, y, z` is not the same thing as `foo = a, foo = b, etc`. Not only will it be right but you'd have actually helped this person

Comment: @pvg well it's not like I skipped 15 chapters of the book I could easily just play around with the code until I get it right as ive been doing for every chapter what I needed was how to separate the argv and that's that. the rest is just a job for Google and if I knew it was going to be this much trouble I would've never asked

Comment: @pvg and you said foo = x,y,z isn't the same as foo = x, foo = y. Care to elaborate? I thought I was

Comment: @AgangDut it's not, that's the crux of your question. I've posted an answer.